# How do I programmatically apply a Drupal input filter?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am currently exporting Drupal data to an external source (XML) programmatically. However, I want the data to run through the site's default Input Format (the filter that runs before user content is displayed on the website) before being written to file.

How do I programmatically apply a Drupal input filter? Is there a specific function call or hook for this purpose? If so, links/advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are looking for [`check_markup` (D6)](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/check_markup/6), [`check_markup` (D7)](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/check_markup/7)

Comment: The question is about input filter, not input format. Input format consists of filters and `check_markup()` works with formats, not filters.